# Wget returning error: "Unable to establish SSL connection."

Tags: download, ssl, website, wget

When I try to run Wget with the following options:

```
E:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin>wget -p --html-extension --convert-links --no-check-certificate https://minecraft.net/en-us/
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = E:\Program Files\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
--2017-02-24 10:38:01--  https://minecraft.net/en-us/
Resolving minecraft.net... 52.84.24.33, 52.84.24.150, 52.84.24.230, ...
Connecting to minecraft.net|52.84.24.33|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

I get the error: `Unable to establish SSL connection.` The website that I am trying to download is safe.

I have also tried to change the protocol to SSLv3, but it still is not working.

Can someone tell me why it is doing this and how to get around it?

Comment: What type fo connnection is this server expecting?  It migh be configured to support (SSLv1, SSLv3, SSLv3, TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, TLS 1.2) or any combination of those possible choices.  Does a connection to this website work within a browser, on the same PC and connection, your attempting to connect to it with `wget`?

Comment: I can access this website on my computer normally using Chrome with no problems.

Comment: I look's like it may be using the SSLv3 connection as it states the following in the error: `routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3`.

Comment: That is what, wget is attempting to use, but the server is rejecting that connection because SSLv3 isn't secure.

Comment: According to other answers below, it looks like the protocol is TLSv1.0

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) shows, only TLSv1.0 and above are supported by minecraft.net. You can't use SSLv3 with it. It's likely that your version of wget doesn't support this (possibly due to being too old). Try upgrading it.

Answer (score 26):

You can find a newer version here: [Windows binaries of GNU Wget](https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/)

It works fine, I had the same problem.

Comment: The exact file link is here: https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/releases/wget-1.19.1-win32.zip

Comment: Years later, version `1.20.3` was available... but it had problems. I had to run this to get a working version (under Windows): `choco install wget --version 1.20`

Comment: I have the problem that all 64bit Versions of this wget there always crush after some seconds of downloading a file over https

Comment: I had wget 1.11.x - moving up to 1.20.3 resolved this for me as well. Thanks.

Comment: Version 1.21.1 at https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/ worked for me

Answer (score 4):

I downloaded the 32-bit `.exe` file. It works.

```
wget.exe np -r -nH -L --cut-dirs=2 https://coast.noaa.gov/htdata/lidar1_z/geoid12a/data/3654/20090316_249102.laz
```

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar error, but in my case only “Unable to establish SSL connection.” was shown without explanation. 
I have used a WinWget, which included a wget compiled without SSL support. Solved by downloading full version from https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/

Answer (score 2):

You may want to add `--secure-protocol=TLSv1` option.

Check also if installed OpenSSL supporting TLS by running:

```
openssl s_client -connect minecraft.net:443 -tls1
```

Comment: `--secure-protocol+TLSv1` Gave me the same error that I got before.

Comment: @WilliamV. I just run the same `wget ...` string by copy/pasting it from your question without changes on debian 8 jessie and it works without any error. Since you using some Window's port of `wget`, it looks like linked OpenSSL lib is outdated. Try to setup virtual machine with bare(non gui) debian and it should work. Another option, - use [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), it always comes with most recent versions of all programs. I just check the same `wget...` from cygwin, and it worked too.

Comment: I can't install cygwin. Is it possible that I could try this on Xubuntu with Wget? I have a Linux machine that is running Xubuntu currently.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and using a newer wget as mentioned in other answers solved it.  However I'm not into installing binaries from random sites, if you're on Windows as the OP is and have [WSL installed with Ubuntu](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) then you can open a bash shell and have the latest ubuntu wget. If wget not installed:

`sudo apt install wget`

You can easily get to your windows stuff via
`cd /mnt/c` (or d or whichever drive)

Answer (score 0):

adding to [the accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/1182481/232770):
if you're on windows and don't find or don't trust a reasonably new wget, try curl instead. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16216825/829755) it may already be included in Windows 10.

Comment: You might try adding your information as a comment to the accepted answer.